# How does a process know the location of another's stdout, stderr, stdin?

Tags: io

I want to know how standard I/O channels are handled in more depth.
Processes have their own stdout, stderr, stdin channels where they can read/write. As far as I know, these are stored as temporary files at least on Linux, not sure about Windows, but the point is how does a process know where is another's stdin in the memory or on a hard drive for example? There are built-in functions in most languages that manage these channels, and all you need is the process id as a parameter and there is usually a function that lets you write to stdin with that, but how does the given language know where the stdin is of that other process?

Is the OS handling this? The OS tells where these channels should be and it can then tell this to other processes?

There must be some kind of standard to hold this together so "stranger" applications can communicate with each other.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: This is a theoritical question so I am not sure if "Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs" makes any sense in this case. I've done research but I couldn't find a clear answer to my question. I am sorry if my question doesn't feel enough specific, I'll think of a way to make it clearer.

Comment: There aren't multiple stdout, stdin and stderr channels; there's only one of each, assigned by the operating system itself.  It's possible to redirect stdin, stdout and stderr to different targets on a process by process basis, but it's all handled by the operating system.  The "locations" of stdin, stdout and stderr remain fixed, from the program's perspective.

Comment: "As far as I know" normally implies you did some previous research, even if that only involved remembering hearsay :-) In this case, that's obviously not enough, as stdin/out/err are not stored in temporary files on Linux. Read and understand https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor. Processes generally don't know or need to know where other processes' input/output data is, they are normally plumbed with pipes by their creating shell, or they connect to sockets to communicate.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams

Answer (score 3):

Under Unix, processes have file descriptors (fd). They are numbered, and the numbers are unique to a process. The fd 0 is stdin, fd 1 and 2 are stdout and stderr, respectively. These initial file descriptors are inherited from the parent process, but can be changed later.

A file descriptor might refer to an opened file on any mounted file system, but there are other types of file descriptors as well. For example, it could be a TCP socket connection, or a pipe. A pipe can be created with the pipe() syscall and creates two file descriptors, a read end and a write end. Data written to the reader can be later read through the writer. The operating system buffers the contents of the pipe, but no temporary files are involved.

A process can launch child processes that are connected via a pipe. In pseudocode:

```c
int pipefd[2];
pipe(pipefd);

pid_t reader = fork();
if (reader == 0) {
  // in child process: reader
  close(pipefd[0]);  // close write end
  dup2(pipefd[1], stdin);

  ... // now pipe is stdin
  exit();
}

pid_t writer = fork();
if (writer == 0) {
  // in child process: writer
  close(pipefd[1]);  // close read end
  dup2(pipefd[0], stdout);

  ... // now pipe is stdout
  exit();
}
```

Similar code is executed by a shell like Bash if you pipe programs together, like `echo foo | wc -c`.

As an introspection feature, Linux has the procfs pseudo-filesystem that lets us access open file descriptors of any process (for which we have access permissions). For example, the stdin of process 123 can be accessed as the pseudo-file `/proc/123/fd/0`. But this is just an interface to the Linux kernel, as an alternative to syscalls. This does not mean that file descriptors are stored on disk.

Answer (score 1):

> the point is how does a process know where is another's stdin in the memory or on a hard drive for example?

They typically know it by telling them!  A (parent) process that creates a child process can control where the child's stdin/stdout goes.

A good example of this is the various command line shells, which allow commands that redirect the output of one process into the input of another process (in memory via pipes), or send results to/from files on disc.

Beyond the shells, many multi-process applications do this: one (parent) process launches the other processes, and thus configures the child processes: the parent tells the other processes where their in/out should go.